# bash shell script not working as intended using cmp with output redirection

Tags: bash, output, stderr, io-redirection, cmp

I am trying to write a bash script that remove duplicate files from a folder, keeping only one copy.
The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f1 in `find ./ -name "*.txt"`
do
    if test -f $f1
    then
        for f2 in `find ./ -name "*.txt"`
        do
            if [ -f $f2 ] && [ "$f1" != "$f2" ]
            then
                # if cmp $f1 $f2 &> /dev/null # DOES NOT WORK
                if cmp $f1 $f2
                then
                    rm $f2
                    echo "$f2 purged"
                fi 
            fi
        done
    fi 
done
```

I want to redirect the output and stderr to `/dev/null` to avoid printing them to screen.. But using the commented statement this script does not work as intended and removes all files but the first..

I'll give more informations if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from the shebang, you have several potential bugs in your code (unquoted variables, parsing ls, etc.) You can see them yourself if you paste your code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ (it also finds the `&>` error )

Comment: Awesome shellcheck. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&>` is bash syntax, you'll need to change the shebang line (first line) to #!/bin/bash (or the appropriate path to bash.

Or if you're really using the Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`), then you have to use old-style redirection, i.e.

```
cmp ... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Also, I think the `&>` was only introduced in bash 4, so if you're using bash, 3.X you'll still need the old-style redirections.

IHTH

Answer (score 8):

Few comments:

First, the:

```
for f1 in `find ./ -name "*.txt"`
do
    if test -f $f1
    then
```

is the same as (find only plain files with the `txt` extension)

```
for f1 in `find ./ -type f -name "*.txt"`
```

Better syntax (bash only) is

```
for f1 in $(find ./ -type f -name "*.txt")
```

and finally the whole is wrong, because if the filename contains a space, the `f1` variable will not get the full path name. So instead the `for` do:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print | while read -r f1
```

and as @Sir Athos pointed out, the filename can contain `\n` so the best is to use

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f1
```

Second:

Use `"$f1"` instead of `$f1` - again, because the `$f1` can contain space.

Third:

doing N*N comparisons is not very effective. You should make a checksum (md5 or better sha256) for every `txt` file. When the checksum is identical - the files are dups.

If you don't trust checksums, simply compare only files what has identical checksums. Files with different checksum are SURE not duplicates. ;)

Making checksums are slow to, so you should 1st compare ony files with the `same size`. Different sized files are not duplicates...

You can skip empty `txt files` - they are duplicates all :).

so the final command can be:

```
find -not -empty -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d |\
xargs -I% -n1 find -type f -name \*.txt -size %c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum |\
sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
```

commented:

```
#find all non-empty file with the txt extension and print their size (in bytes)
find . -not -empty -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%s\n" |\

#sort the sizes numerically, and keep only duplicated sizes
sort -rn | uniq -d |\

#for each sizes (what are duplicated) find all files with the given size and print their name (path)
xargs -I% -n1 find . -type f -name \*.txt -size %c -print0 |\

#make an md5 checksum for them
xargs -0 md5sum |\

#sort the checksums and keep duplicated files separated with an empty line
sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
```

The output now, you can simply edit the output file and decide what want remove and what file want keep.

Comment: A much better answer. I withdraw mine. Good luck all.

Comment: Ok, that's a nice answer. I didn't not use checksums because they are slow while cmp stops at the first different line between two files, but your argument is valid (using size). I'll learn this tip. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to run find a second time: have the first one output the filename with the size: `find . -not -empty -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%8s %p\n" | sort -n | uniq -Dw 8 | cut -c 10- | xargs md5sum | sort | uniq -Dw 32 | cut -c 35-`

Comment: It isn't very common, but it's legal for filenames to contain `\n`. So, instead of `find -print | while read`, it is safer to use: `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f1`

Comment: @shellter undelete your deleted answer, because you're answered to the question, where is the problem in his script. :) All other answers gives a solutions, but no one answers the question: where is the problem... ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll take it (I like seeing my rep over 11,600 ;-) ). As there's a fair discussion on this topic, then my addition adds to the overall info. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

Credit to @kobame for this answer: this is really a comment but for the formatting.

You don't need to call find twice, print out the size and the filename in the find command

```
find . -not -empty -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%8s %p\n" |
# find the files that have duplicate sizes
sort -n | uniq -Dw 8 | 
# strip off the size and get the md5 sum
cut -c 10- | xargs md5sum
```

An example

```
$ cat a.txt
this is file a
$ cat b.txt
this is file b
$ cat c.txt
different contents 
$ cp a.txt d.txt
$ cp b.txt e.txt
$ find . -not -empty -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%8s %p\n" |
sort -n | uniq -Dw 8 | cut -c 10- | xargs md5sum
```

```
76fd4c1589ef708d9203f3cf09cfd032  ./a.txt
e2d75fd6a1080efb6230d0608b1f9014  ./b.txt
76fd4c1589ef708d9203f3cf09cfd032  ./d.txt
e2d75fd6a1080efb6230d0608b1f9014  ./e.txt
```

To keep one and delete the rest, I would pipe the output into:

```
...  | awk '++seen[$1] > 1 {print $2}' | xargs echo rm
```

```
rm ./d.txt ./e.txt
```

Remove the `echo` if your testing is satisfactory.

Like many complex pipelines, filenames containing newlines will break it.

Answer (score 2):

All nice answers, so only one short suggestion: you can install and use the

```
fdupes -r .
```

from the man:

> Searches the given path for duplicate files. Such files are found by
>   comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures, followed by a byte-by-byte
>   comparison.

Added by @Francesco

```
fdupes -rf . | xargs rm -f
```

for remove dupes. (the `-f` in fdupes omit the 1st occurence the file, so list only dupes)

Comment: Complete command is `fdupes -rf . | xargs rm -f` .. if you want add it as reference.